# How to debug Go tests with param "./..." in VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I usually run `go test ./...` to run all tests in my project.

How can I set up `launch.json` to debug every tests that normally `go test ./...` runs?

Comment: What do you mean by "debug every test"?  Do you simply want to _run_ every test? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the [Go extension for VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go):

As the [vscode-go's documentation says](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code#sample-configuration-to-debug-all-tests-in-the-package), you could use the following:

```
{
    "name": "Launch test package",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "test",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Note that you're specifying a new mode called "test".

You have to install `delve` in order to debug code using VSCode. You can install it by yourself or use the `Go: Install/Update Tools` command from VSCode. Read the documentation I mention first for more information.

Comment: This only tests inside `workspaceFolder` but not tests in the folders under it!

Comment: {
    "name": "Launch test package",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "test",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}"
}

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
{
   "name": "Launch test package",
   "type": "go",
   "request": "launch",
    "mode": "test",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/controllers" 
}
```